# What's up with my $PATH?

Tags: linux, command-line, environment-variables

I'm trying to make my personal install of cmake the default option for my user by adding a directory to `PATH`, but I'm confused, and I'm hoping to get some help.

I'm remotely logged in to some Linux environment. If I type `echo $0` I get `-tcsh` as output. Everything I find online says that the PATH variable in tcsh is space separated, but if I type `echo $PATH` I get a list of directories separated by `:`. This is bash-like.

If I type `PATH=foo`, I get `Command not found`. If I instead try `set PATH = foo`, I can `echo $PATH` and get `foo`. This is tcsh-like.

If I type `which cmake` I get `/bin/cmake`. If I use `set PATH = foo` to add my personal install of cmake to the start of `PATH`, I still get `/bin/cmake`. This seems like `PATH` isn't being used at all.

How do I get `which cmake` to find my install, and what am I missing that makes the above so confusing for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space-separated search path in tcsh is `$path`. Note that variable names are case-sensitive.

```
> echo $path
/sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/games /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin
> echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Adding new paths works like this:

```
set path = ($path /usr/local/sbin)
```

It also modifies the `$PATH` variable to match.

Keep in mind that to override a system binary, your addition to `$path` must come first.

Comment: I though I tried whether it was case sensitive at some point, but apparently I didn't. Your answer does everything I asked for, top notch.